# How to retain last file of every day and delete remaining for the dates in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

Case: I have a folder in Linux where the files huge files will be created/generated every day. Now I would like to retain the last file and delete the remaining files every day

Example

```
abc_2022_08_08_04:47:39.done       08-Aug-2022 04:31           119864435  
abc_2022_08_08_07:47:39.done       08-Aug-2022 07:30           119875333  
abc_2022_08_09_04:47:37.done       09-Aug-2022 04:30           119995734  
abc_2022_08_09_05:47:39.done       09-Aug-2022 05:30           120002986  
abc_2022_08_09_06:47:38.done       09-Aug-2022 06:30           120011628  
abc_2022_08_09_07:47:39.done       09-Aug-2022 07:30           120037486  
abc_2022_08_10_04:47:38.done       10-Aug-2022 04:30           120198109  
abc_2022_08_10_05:47:38.done       10-Aug-2022 05:31           120222712  
abc_2022_08_10_06:47:41.done       10-Aug-2022 06:30           120249157
```

We need the output:

```
abc_2022_08_08_07:47:39.done       08-Aug-2022 07:30           119875333  
abc_2022_08_09_07:47:39.done       09-Aug-2022 07:30           120037486  
abc_2022_08_10_06:47:41.done       10-Aug-2022 06:30           120249157
```

I'm in mid of writing the following script, however, couldn't get through the logic or looping of how it can be done. It looks like needs some expert's advice or help.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at logrotate. It's a specific tool very used to rotate logs, but it can also bu used to rotate other kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

With the list of files in a file called `listing` this seems to do what you're asking for:

```
$ sort -k2,3 listing
abc_2022_08_08_04:47:39.done       08-Aug-2022 04:31           119864435
abc_2022_08_08_07:47:39.done       08-Aug-2022 07:30           119875333
abc_2022_08_09_04:47:37.done       09-Aug-2022 04:30           119995734
abc_2022_08_09_05:47:39.done       09-Aug-2022 05:30           120002986
abc_2022_08_09_06:47:38.done       09-Aug-2022 06:30           120011628
abc_2022_08_09_07:47:39.done       09-Aug-2022 07:30           120037486
abc_2022_08_10_04:47:38.done       10-Aug-2022 04:30           120198109
abc_2022_08_10_05:47:38.done       10-Aug-2022 05:31           120222712
abc_2022_08_10_06:47:41.done       10-Aug-2022 06:30           120249157

$ awk  -v start="$(awk '{print $2}' <(sort -k2,3 listing|head -n 1) )"  '{if( $2!=start ){print prev;start=$2}else{prev=$0};}END{print prev}' <(sort -k2,3 listing)
abc_2022_08_08_07:47:39.done       08-Aug-2022 07:30           119875333
abc_2022_08_09_07:47:39.done       09-Aug-2022 07:30           120037486
abc_2022_08_10_06:47:41.done       10-Aug-2022 06:30           120249157
```

What does it do?

`"$(awk '{print $2}' <(sort -k2,3 listing|head -n 1) )"` sort the file, print the datefield

`awk  -v begin="$(awk '{print $2}' <(sort -k2,3 listing|head -n 1) )"` store the datefield (the oldest because we sorted it) in a variable called `start`.

Then we iterate over the same sorted output, comparing the date field of each line the variable `start`.  If there's a change the previous line will have held the oldest entry of the previous date.

Comment: Finally, I got that command. 

"find *.done -daystart -mtime -1 -print | head -n -1 | xargs -i rm {}"
First to find out that modified files at the current date and then keep last modified file and remaining files has been removed.